# How to echo a variable correctly in Centos7

Tags: bash, echo

I have a version value which I want to echo like this

```
The file version 1.1 is available
```

For this I'm using my $version variable which contains the value 1.1. But for whatever reason, I'm not able to echo this single line. It always gives me the result -

```
 is available
```

The echo command prints only what comes after $version. These are the echo commands I have tried

```
echo "The file version" ${version} "is available"
echo "The file version ${version} is available"
echo "The file version $version is available"
echo "The file version" "$version" "is available"
echo "The file version" "${version}" "is available"
```

I even tried the same with `echo -n` and `printf` commands, but it does not work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p version`?

Comment: `echo "The file version $version is available"` or `echo "The file version ${version} is available"` are correct and preferred. Or equally preferred `printf "The file version %s is available\n" "$version"`

Comment: All the above commands work for me. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the output you're seeing, I'm fairly sure your `$version` variable includes a carriage return (`'\r'`) character. The value is being printed, but it's overwritten after the `'\r'` sends the cursor to the beginning of the line.

You can verify this by typing

```
printf "%q\n" "$version"
```

or

```
echo "$version" | cat -A
```

You probably did something like:

```
version="$(some_command some_option)"
```

where the output used Windows-style line endings.

One of many ways to avoid this (perhaps not the cleanest solution) is:

```
version="$(some_command some_option | tr -d '\r')"
```

Comment: my version was assigned like this - version=${var3/'</value></param>'/}. So I did this -  version="${var3/'</value></param>'/} | tr -d '\r')". And I got the output as -  | tr -d '\r') is available

Comment: @Sandeep That's not going to invoke the `tr` command. You'd need an `echo`. Apparently the `'\r'` character is in `$var3`; look at whatever sets that.

Comment: You can put `set -x` before the problem section to make the shell print commands as it executes them, which can be very useful for tracing what values are being passed/used where. You'll probably see things like `version=$'1.1\r'`.

Comment: `version=${version//$'\r'}` may also be used to remove `\r` characters

Comment: Thank you all. It was certainly the \r that was causing the issue. Fixed it now :)